# How to add hotkey for mouse 4th button to delete in edit mode

Tags: 3d-view, customization, shortcut

I can get my mouse 4th button to map to delete in object mode but not in edit mode. I also don't see an edit mode keyboard configuration section in Blender preferences menu.

Comment: The edit mode kb configuration is called "mesh" here (just below "edit mode"). I believe you'll need to add a short cut for "delete" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the *User Preferences*, and head to the *Input* tab. Open the ***3D View*** section, and inside of that the ***Mesh*** section. Now scroll to the bottom of the *Mesh* section and you will find an *Add New* button.

Now what to put in the *Identifier* field?

If you want the 4th mouse button to simply bring up the menu (like pressing <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>) then use `wm.call_menu` as the *Identifier* (top field) and put `VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_delete` in the name filed that will appear at the bottom. Yes it will be grayed out, but you *can* still click in it and add the text.
[image: keyboard shortcut]

---

Or if you want to be able to directly delete, say vertices, by pressing the 4th button, then set up a shortcut like this:
[image: keyboard shortcut settings]
Now the shortcut is calling `mesh.delete` directly instead of calling for the menu. Then just pick which *Type* you want to delete. You'll notice that I have "Ctrl" checked there. This way I can press the 4th button to open up the delete menu. Yet I still can directly delete vertices, edges, and faces by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> respectively.
You have to add more shortcut entries for each "type" you want to delete.

Comment: This was super helpful and would have taken me a really long time to have figured out.  Thanks David!